# Lightest Debian Linux Distribution : Console Only - StandAlone (not net install)

Tags: linux, debian, iso, small-distribution

Please suggest to me the lightest Debian Linux release with console only (no GUI). Please don't suggest any net install like `netinst`. I need an ISO of that release which is capable to boot and install from.

Later I'll install my own chosen GUI and applications for my needs from Debian/Ubuntu repositories.

Comment: Dial up connection?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm pretty sure that you can choose what you want when install debian.
Follow this [link](http://saidkhorramshahgol.wordpress.com/2008/12/13/how-to-debian-minimal-installation/) for more information.

Comment: Basically this. Grab the big fat DVD iso and you will have most packages on disk. Choose minimal installation.

Answer (score 1):

Very late answer, but [TurnKey Linux](https://www.turnkeylinux.org/) is a pretty minimalist, commandline only distro. The latest [Core ISO](https://www.turnkeylinux.org/core) (which can also run live) clocks in at just over 200MB.

Core is the base headless appliance and is based on Debian Jessie. It does include some extras which you may not want to trim it down even more (Webmin and Webshell for starters).